# Newtonian mechanics involving rotation of 2 discs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Two uniform discs of mass $(2M,2R)$ and $(M,R)$ are rotating with angular velocities $ω_0$ and $4ω_0$ as shown. They are brought in contact and after some time there is no slipping at the surface. Find the final angular velocity of the smaller disc.

[image]

I am unable to understand the concept in this problem. Can anyone please tell me about the concept involved?

Comment: look into conservation of angular momentum

Comment: Depending on the conditions, angular momentum might not be conserved. Similar question: [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314063/conservation-of-angular-momentum-exercise](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314063/conservation-of-angular-momentum-exercise)